# Almost similar SQL code blocks with few difference of values in .TXT file to identify

Tags: pattern-matching

I am a follower of this site for the past several years and I have benefited many times. This is my first time posting for a sample scenario I am stuck on.

Scenario :: I have two .SQL files that have almost similar piece of Code with differences of parameter values(e.g IDs,names). Now I need to capture each similar block of each file. With this you can assume there are 15-20 blocks like Deletion/Insertion with the same syntax, but different values. And I want to identify and highlight the differences using Java.

Could anyone help me to determine how I can specify similar blocks and and distinguish.

Thanks for looking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a *clone detector*.  This is a tool that finds similar chunks of code across one or multiple files.

Our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/) is one of these tools.  It operates by comparing the program structure rather than the program text, so changes formatting and comments do not confuse it. (It uses actual language parsers to exrtract the program structure; many other detectors only match text or program tokens).   Further, CloneDR will discover *similar* code blocks (with a high degree of similarity), and can precisely identify how they are different (we call the differences "parameters" as you have intuited).  You can see the reports it produces at the site link.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to build an own tool will be used for a specific case. So I want technical guide that how can I proceed with String checking and mismatch identifying.. Thanks for looking.

Comment: OK, see my paper on how to build a clone detector: "Clone Detectuion Using Abstract Syntax Trees" http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/ICSM98.pdf   You are going to find out this is a lot of work.